# what is mapVal in google fit api for heartrate and if what is values of mapVal?

Tags: java, google-fit, heartbeat, fitbit, heartrate

```
{
  "minStartTimeNs": "1636419661000000000",
  "maxEndTimeNs": "1636439595000000000",
  "dataSourceId": "derived:com.google.heart_rate.bpm:com.google.android.gms:merge_heart_rate_bpm",
  "point": [
    {
      "startTimeNanos": "1636435597175000000",
      "endTimeNanos": "1636435597175000000",
      "dataTypeName": "com.google.heart_rate.bpm",
      "originDataSourceId": "raw:com.google.heart_rate.bpm:com.google.android.apps.fitness:user_input",
      "value": [
        {
          "fpVal": 98.061103820800781,
          "mapVal": [
            
          ]
        }
      ],
      "modifiedTimeMillis": "1636436192037"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Based on the docs. Mapval is a list which has valid key space and units for the corresponding value of each entry should be documented as part of the data type definition. Keys should be kept small whenever possible. Data streams with large keys and high data frequency may be down sampled.

Comment: please refer to https://googleapis.dev/dotnet/Google.Apis.Fitness.v1/latest/api/Google.Apis.Fitness.v1.Data.Value.html#Google_Apis_Fitness_v1_Data_Value_MapVal

Answer (score 0):

`mapVal` is simply there as an artefact of the fact that JSON can't distinguish between an unset map field and an empty map in the map field.

It will never be non-empty for `com.google.heart_rate.bpm` data: you can see that only 1 float-valued field is used [in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/fit/datatypes/health#heart_rate).

You can ignore the `mapVal`.